# Como hacer un select atraves de c# y base de datos mysql y mostrarlo en un label

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual

Tengo este codigo donde quiero hacer un select atraves de un label pero me muestra un error en datasource(checar ultima linea del codigo) donde me sale el siguiente mensaje:

Error   CS1061  "Label" no contiene una definición para "DataSource" ni un método de extensión accesible "DataSource" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "Label" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

o tambien se podrá de otra manera hacer un select  y me lo muestre en un label?

```
 private void Resultados_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Cadenaconexion = "Server=localhost;User id=root;Database=Odontologia;Password=;";
        // Conexion.ConnectionString = Cadenaconexion;
        MySqlConnection Conexion = new MySqlConnection();
        //Conexion.Open();
        MySqlCommand comandobus = new MySqlCommand();
        comandobus.Connection = Conexion;
        //MySqlDataAdapter com = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT caracteristica FROM busquedaatras", Cadenaconexion);
        MySqlDataAdapter com = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT caracteristica FROM busquedaatras", Cadenaconexion);
        com.Fill(tbl);
        Conexion.Close();
        label7.DataSource = tbl; **aqui esta el error en la parte de datasource**
    }
```

Comment: Ese error te da pq estas accediendo a una propiedad q los label no tiene, en los label la propiedad datasource no existe,

Comment: que es lo q devuelve tu consulta, que es lo q quieres hace exactamente, da mas detalles

Comment: Primero que nada, un label no tiene una propiedad DataSource, esa propiedad lo tiene en el caso de WinForm un Picker, un DataTable o ListBox y otro elemento que me falte que carga una lista de elementos. El intelisense te deberia estar avisando que no existe esa propiedad cuando la escribis.

Answer (score 0):

Como te explique en el comentario arriba un label no tiene un datasource porque no carga una lista de elementos, viendo tu consulta entiendo que puede venir uno o mas registros de una sola columna, lo cual podrias cargarla al label de la siguiente forma o en un componente que acepte una lista de elementos.

```
    private void Resultados_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Cadenaconexion = "Server=localhost;User id=root;Database=Odontologia;Password=;";
        // Conexion.ConnectionString = Cadenaconexion;
        MySqlConnection Conexion = new MySqlConnection();
        //Conexion.Open();
        MySqlCommand comandobus = new MySqlCommand();
        comandobus.Connection = Conexion;
        //MySqlDataAdapter com = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT caracteristica FROM busquedaatras", Cadenaconexion);
        MySqlDataAdapter com = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT caracteristica FROM busquedaatras", Cadenaconexion);
        com.Fill(tbl);
        Conexion.Close();
       //Correccion de DataSource por Text
        label7.Text = tbl; 
       //Deberias usar una tabla o listbox
       Listbox1.DataSource = tbl;
    }
```